# how to find parentid from a column where record is avible inside an item in oracle

Tags: oracle10g

I have four columns

```
Item        Subitem     subitemid   Itemid
A1001        B110       1111        2111
A1002        B112       1112        2112
A1003        B113       1113        2113    
  B1001      C113       1114        2114
  B1002      C114       1116        2115
     C1001   D114       1117        2116
     C1002   D115       1118        2117
D1001        E115       1119        2118
  E1002      F116       1120        2119
  E1002      G117       1121        2120
     F1003   H118       1122        2121
     G1004   I119       1123        2122
H1001        J120       1124        2123
```

Subitem is available inside item and subitemid is the primary key for subitem.
In item colum, 2 space indent at every level where a item belong to inside an item.
Need a select query where one more column can be shown for the table in which parentsubitemid shows the subitemid where a item is available inside a item.

For example item A1003 is parent item for the C113,C114 where subitemid 1113 will be the parent id for the C113,C114 and B1002 is parentsubitem for D114 and D115 where 1116 is parentsubitem id for B1002.

Comment: I can't follow your last paragraph at all. I can't tell if that's all to work out the value you want for a single row, or multiple values for multiple rows. Can you try to break that down a bit, and show the expected results for all the sample data, and your current query?

Comment: B113 is the parentsubitem for C113 and C114 like this C114 is parentsubitem for D114 and D115 so the new column should show the parentsubitemid 1113 for c113 and c114 and parentsubitemid 1116 for D114 and D115.

Answer (score 0):

```
with your_table as (
select 'A1001' Item,        'B110' Subitem,      1111 subitemid,       2111 Itemid from dual
union all select  'A1002',        'B112',       1112,        2112 from dual
union all select  'A1003',        'B113',       1113,        2113 from dual    
union all select  '  B1001',      'C113',       1114,        2114 from dual
union all select  '  B1002',      'C114',       1116,        2115 from dual
union all select  '    C1001',   'D114',       1117,        2116 from dual
union all select  '    C1002',   'D115',       1118,        2117 from dual
union all select  'D1001',        'E115',       1119,        2118 from dual
union all select  '  E1002',      'F116',       1120,        2119 from dual
union all select  '  E1002',      'G117',       1121,        2120 from dual
union all select  '    F1003',   'H118',       1122,        2121 from dual
union all select  '    G1004',   'I119',       1123,        2122 from dual
union all select  'H1001',        'J120',       1124,        2123 from dual
), 
tab_level as (
  -- calculate level for each row
  select item, subitem, subitemid, itemid, 
         -- regexp_instr finds a position of the first not space symbol 
         (regexp_instr(item, '[^ ]')-1)/2+1 lvl 
  from your_table
),
tree as (
  -- make a hierarchical structure (find parent for each row) 
  select item, subitem, subitemid, itemid, 
         lag(itemid, lvl-1) over(order by itemid) parent_itemid
         -- analytic function which gives (lvl-1)th previous itemid
         -- it is important that the rows sorted by itemid go in the same order as in your example otherwise this query won't work 
  from tab_level
) 
-- final query, use CONNECT BY to find the desired extra info
select item, subitem, subitemid, itemid,    
       -- unary operator, gives the "root" itemid     
       connect_by_root itemid parentsubitemid,
       -- shows all the parents separated by /
       sys_connect_by_path(item, '/') whole_path
from tree
start with itemid = parent_itemid
connect by nocycle prior itemid = parent_itemid;
```